# Setting a placeholder image in an MvxImageView control

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a large collection of search results bound using an MvxImageView control. As the application downloads each image there is sometimes a small wait whilst the image renders. Currently this means the search results are white before they are rendered.

I wish to have a placeholder image in MvxImageView in the same manner that you could place one in a standard ImageView control.

This is the code.

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:id="@+id/item_searchresult_imageView"
  android:src="@drawable/product_placeholder"
  android:layout_gravity="center|top"
  android:layout_width="170dp"
  android:layout_height="128dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl SearchResult.ProductImageId, Converter=PowerStorageImage" />
```

The issue is that the line

```
 android:src="@drawable/product_placeholder"
```

doesn't seem to be set properly before the main image is loaded, and the search result is still black white prior to loading.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I should also point out that in some instances there isn't actually an image for the result, and in that case I wish have the placeholder image remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are suggesting is the same as the placeholder pattern used in the BookSellers sample:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:id="@+id/BookImageView"
  android:layout_width="80dp"
  android:layout_height="80dp"
  android:padding="8dp"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl AmazonImageUrl"
  />
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20BestSellers/BestSellers/BestSellers.Droid/Resources/Layout/ListItem_Book.axml#L11

It seems to work OK there for the case where the `ImageUrl` takes a few seconds to download.

If you have some customer use case where there is sometimes an image and sometimes now, then you could maybe try writing some code for your specific case, eg:

- use a valueconverter to detect when the ImageUrl is invalid and replace it with some custom url (maybe a local file)
- use a custom control instead of MvxImageView to write some custom handling (the control could either inherit from or replace MvxImageView - it's code is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxImageView.cs and it's easy to write your own custom controls - see custom control tutorials within http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com)

Some of the information from this (rather confused) question may help - [MVVMCross Downloadcache - ProgressView during loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036473/mvvmcross-downloadcache-progressview-during-loading/19044756#19044756)